# Как задать глобально папку node_modules для всех новых Angular - приложений в Windows?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

Начинаю пробовать `Angular`. При создании нового Angular - приложения с помощью команды `ng new app-name` создается новая папка, внутри которой лежит еще одна папка `node_modules`. Сама команда `ng new` достаточно долго выполняется. Я подозреваю, что это связано с загрузкой всех модулей в node_modules.

Как можно загрузить `node_modules` один раз в какую-нибудь папку (условно, `D:\node_modules`) и при создании нового проекта ангуляр подтягивать все модули из этой папки? А то постоянно грузить 200+ МБ из интернета при каждом создании приложения - такое себе. Также хотелось бы узнать, есть ли команда, которая позволяет обновлять эти модули.

И общий вопрос: нужно ли так вообще делать?

Comment: теоретически и абстрактно такое возможно, но вопрос зачем? при запуске `ng new` пакетный менеджер тянет последние версии всех пакетов, а так ты хочшеь вручную каждый раз апдейтить версии всех пакетов и версии пакетов от которых они зависят? у меня 50+ проектов локально на angular, но я никогда не парился, что оно там скачивает какие-то 200 метров + на линуксе это как-то быстро (я конечно не знаю что там на винде, но все жалуются что медленно)

Comment: @overthesanity как вариант, можно было бы написать скрипт для консольки, который перед созданием нового проекта обновлял в глобальной папке все модули. Но теперь я понимаю, что в скорости выигрыша может и не быть. Просто не понимаю, неужели все эти пакеты нужны будут для разработки? Наверняка там есть лишние пакеты, которые накиданы на всякий случай. Сделали бы как в nuget-пакетах в вижле: подгружай только то, что тебе нужно

Comment: ты все усложняешь максимально )) как говорил классик `by default doing extra work is bad, so unless they can bring up an argument why that extra work SHOULD be done; by default it should not`. я, лично, не вижу в этом смысла, но у каждого свое субъективное виденье и каждый имеет на это право. В антихрупкости есть хороший подход - доказывать должны те, кто предлагают что-то новое или нестандартное, а не те, кто следует заведенному, простому или естественному порядку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Установка**

`ng new project -skipInstall=true` - не будет устанавливать пакеты с `packege.json`. После того, как проект создасться вы можете отредактировать файл `packege.json`, после чего запустить `npm install` - установяться все пакеты с файла `packege.json`. Если хотите установить пакеты глобально, то используйте команду `npm install -g`; либо вы можете указать папку, куда ставить так - `npm install <folder>`

---

**Обновление пакетов**

`npm update имя_пакета` - обновляет определенный пакет

`npm update --save` - обновит все пакеты, однако на те версии, которые допустимы в package.json.

Чтобы поставить самые новые версии нужно вызвать `npm install`

Так `npm root -g` можно посмотреть глобальный каталог, куда ставятся пакеты

---

На счет стоит-ли хранить пакеты глобально - однозначного ответа не дам... Некоторые пакеты стоит, например `Angular/cli`, а такие пакеты, как `bootstrap` или `DataTable` - стоит хранить локально (т к в разных проектах могут быть разные версии).

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону nrwl nx, этот дев тул позволяет сделать одинаковые либы и зависимости для нескольких проектов, не только angular, так же nestjs, ionic и тд.

Answer (score 0):

Да не будет это работать.

Сам node будет искать node_modules в родительских папках, пока не найдёт, так что, теоретически, можно было бы бросить папку в корень диска. Но вот тайпскрипту и вебпаку она понадобится в корне проекта, иначе ничего не соберётся.

Comment: Вроде бы вот эта штука должна что-то похожее на то что нужно делать: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link. Я, правда, с ней не разобрался(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну теоретически можно попытаться, но есть сомнения. Вообще она для локальных модулей. Я однажды пытался заменять папку символьной ссылкой и был отличный сюрприз - оно работало по-разному. Хотя ссылка была прям на перемещённую в другое место ту же папку, что там лежала до замены на ссылку.

Comment: У меня на самом деле вообще не вышло её использовать. Хотел в свой проект подключить перекомпиленные исходники ангуляра (чтобы не копировать вручную ~100Mb), однако так и не разобрался как это сделать. Однако такой способ один из разработчиков оного предложил, так что, наверное, в умелых руках оно даже заработает)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если ничего не путаю, там просто создаётся символьная ссылка на каталог. Такую можно и в файловом менеджере создать.

Comment: А на винде такие фокусы работают?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я на винде и делал.